# Does every stack with a connection admit an atlas with a connection?

Tags: stacks, connections, tag-removed, ag.algebraic-geometry

Dear all,

Let $S$ be a scheme in characteristic $0$,
and let $\mathscr{X}/S$ mean a *crystal in Artin stacks over $S$* in the sense of [this handout](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Nov17-19%28Crystals%29.pdf), page 4, Definition 0.5, where we replace the scheme $X$ by a stack $\mathscr{X}$.

Does $\mathscr{X}$ always admit an atlas $Y$ over $S$ which can be enhanced to a crystal of schemes over $S$? In other words, is there a crystal $Y$ in schemes over $S$ together with a map of algebraic stacks $Y\to \mathscr{X}$ which is smooth and surjective?

Comment: Shouldn't this have an algebraic-geometry tag? I'd put it in myself, but my phone browser is not cooperating.

Comment: Do you demand that the cocycle condition hold strictly, or up to 2-isomorphism (together with an additional compatibility)?

Comment: @David: Thank you, I've added it myself!

Comment: @Scott: Thank you for the comment, Scott, I demand the cocycle condition hold only up to isomorphism, which itself must satisfy the natural cocycle condition.